# How to call a Service multiple times?

Tags: android, service

I have four Activities in which i have to upload images in each Activity. I am uploading the image captured into the Webservice using Android Service(background process). 
I want to know how can i call the same Service multiple times.
Let me know if my approach is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: u can use Asyntask and thread concept

Comment: Do you mean to say that if i use Asyntask inside Service then i can send multiple request to Service?

Comment: not sure  but give a try

Comment: Right now i am using Thread class for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call the service again until previous instance stop. **Call of the service will be in queue**. So you should do this using **AsyncTask**.

Read some documents about service and its use.

Here are some : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

http://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html

Comment: Thank you Jatin, I have to call the service one by one. I had researched a lot but couldn't get much support.

Comment: Jatin, I have read this post in Adnrdroid Developer site."       **Service Lifecycle**    

Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand())". Does this means that we cannot call Service multiple times.

Comment: We use services when we want to do a task in background(with or without affecting the Activity like sticky or non sticky services). If you want to call service multiple times declare it as foreground service. But I would suggest you to use AsyncTask in that case. This is recommended by Android.

Comment: To help other readers, please upvote the answer if you think it deserves.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DemoService extends Service{

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(null != intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(null != action) { 
                 if(action.equals(YOURACTION)) {
                       //do your work
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

in your activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(YOURACTION);
startService(intent);
```

just send many time if you want to send many request.

Comment: YOURACTION is some what Intent actions like **Intent.ACTION_CALL**. Am i correct?

Comment: right, Intent can has many actions,each action you can define it to match each work or request.also if you want your service active all the time just turn it to foreground service.